# How to notify main thread from a new thread that it has done something?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, synchronization

I have created a new thread which is discovering devices and continuously updating a variable(whenever there is change) with device names, and my main thread will diplay that devices in UI.

But how can i notify main thread that the variable is changed, and u should update UI.

Main thread is doing something so i cannot block it.

Answer (score 0):

From Python's threading module use Conditional Monitors to block the UI thread while the other threads discover a device and notify the UI thread.

```
condition = threading.Condition()
global update

# Update
condition.acquire()
while not update:
   condition.wait()
update = False
<Update UI>
update.release()

# Discover
condition.acquire()
update = True
<Add discovered device>
condition.notify()
condition.release()
```

Comment: actually i can't block main thread, i need a solution where it gets some notification or signal from new thread and the update UI